Получение текста с кнопки kivy python
Как получить текст с нажатой кнопки в киви? У меня есть цикл, который создаёт кнопки, названия которых получает из базы данных Sqlite. Мне нужно, чтобы зависимости от нажатой кнопки вывелись значения текста с этой кнопки. Как это сделать?
